# In asp.net, MVC, how to show content of original data after clicked EDIT method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I don't know if you can understand my question but I am trying to making this clear.

For now, I have some methods in my controller. And When I click Edit, it supposed to show the original things like the following. But instead of that, I got Nothing in the text boxes. I hope someone could me some advice, thanks!

[image]

Here is my Edit Method in the controller.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(string programid)
    {
        Program program = db.Programs.Find(programid);

        return View(program);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ProgramID,SerialNo,ProgramName,SubmissionDeadline,LevelID,DepartmentID,HierachyL1,HierachyL2,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,AwardAmount,DateReleased,DatePosted,DateOpen,InternalDueDate,Area1,Area2,Area3,Weblink,Word,AgencyID")]Program program)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(program).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("All");
            }
            return View(program);
        }
        catch(DataException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again");
            PopulateDepartmentDropDownList(program.DepartmentID);
        }
        return View(program);
    }
```

For the Model, I just have some variables.

```
 [Table("[RP_Program]")]
public class Program
{
    [Key]
    public string ProgramID { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
    public string ProgramName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SubmissionDeadline { get; set; }
    public int AgencyID { get; set; }
}
```

For the view, Here is part of it, most codes are the same.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Program</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProgramID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProgramID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProgramID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SerialNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SerialNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SerialNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you checked `Program` property contents after executing `db.Programs.Find(programid)`? I think with current setup only `Find` method is very suspicious.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto  Thanks for mentioning that. Seems my `programid` =null , and even `program` = null. Why I shouldn't use `db.programs.Find` here?  If not this one, what should I use?

Comment: Check if the programid is receiving the correct value in the Edit routine, If the programid is incorrect, the Find method will return null. Can you show the View which calls the Edit routine?

Comment: It's a sign that you're not passing `programid` argument value properly. If it comes from `ActionLink`, make sure it contains something like this: `@Html.ActionLink("linktext", "action_name", "controller_name", new { programid = "any value exist in DB" })`, otherwise explain it further.

Comment: @RobAnthony `<td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ProgramID })
        </td>` It is in the view, and I don't know why it does not work. I am using Microsoft default View for every method.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto `@Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Detail", new { id=item.ProgramID }) 
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ProgramID })
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ProgramID }) `
            The Detail is working perfectly. For the Edit, should it be different?

Comment: Yep. You need to match the route value arguments with method argument name like this: `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Controller", new { programid = item.ProgramID })`. In previous code you're passing to `id` argument which not exist in `Edit` action method.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thank you so much!!! It worked. Anyway, forgive my stupidity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to fix is changing argument name to match controller action method argument in `ActionLink` helper:

**View**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "ControllerName", new { programid = item.ProgramID })
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(string programid)
{
    Program program = db.Programs.Find(programid);

    return View(program);
}
```

The previous setup tries to pass the value into `id` argument which doesn't actually exist in `Edit` action method:

```
// incorrect
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ProgramID })
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the parameter names don't match. ASP.NET matches the names to see which parameter gets which value. So in using:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ProgramID })
```

You are sending a parameter with name id, but your Edit routine is looking for a parameter called programid:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string programid)
```

You need to change one of the parameter names so that they match.

Comment: Yeah, I see the problem. Thank you so much!